# How to bind to controller vars from sibling directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to figure out how AngularJS works (or should work). I've got in mind a very simple app with a header, main content and footer. Main content has a mainCtrl that holds most data (no service at this stage). I built header and footer as directives, outside the main content div. Is it possible (or recommended) to access and alter (bind) the mainCtrl variables from my directives? I read that controller and controllerAs, create a copy of the controller, while require might be what I want. But I can't get it to work. Maybe some info and pointing to the right direction could help.
PS Is it much better to have each controller get data using a service/factory? If yes, wouldn't it be efficient to store some data in the controller instead of calling the service all the time?
Please let me know if you need any clarification.

*EDIT: Demo here: [plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DSpqIZTfBYsDRWxrswJX?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="menuApp">
<div header-directive></div>
<hr/>
<div style="min-height: calc(100vh - 400px)" ng-controller="MainController as main">

    <p>Direct access to (mainCtrl) SCOPE user: {{ user }}</p>
   <p>Direct access to mainCtrl user: {{ main.user }}</p>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in main.menuItems"><a ng-href="#/{{ item.toLowerCase() }}">{{ item }}</a></li>
</ul>
<!--<img src="http://ost2.gr/files/gimgs/1_random2.png">-->
<ng-view></ng-view>
</div>

<div footer-directive></div>

Below footer: {{ main.user }}

<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="menuApp.config.js"></script>
<script src="mainController.js"></script>
<script src="ProductsController.js"></script>
<script src="ChartsController.js"></script>
<script src="AboutController.js"></script>
<script src="footerDirective.js"></script>
<script src="headerDirective.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Main Controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('menuApp')
        .controller('MainController', MainController);

    MainController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function MainController($scope) {
        /* jshint validthis: true */
        var vm = this;

        vm.activate = activate;
        vm.title = 'main';

        activate();

        ////////////////

        function activate() {
            vm.menuItems = ['Main', 'Products', 'Charts', 'About'];
            $scope.user = 'SCOPE USER';
            vm.user = 'user from MainController';
        }
    }
})();
```

header Directive:

```
  (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('menuApp')
            .directive('headerDirective', headerDirective);

        headerDirective.$inject = ['$window'];

        /* @ngInject */
        function headerDirective($window) {
            // Usage:
            // 
            // Creates:
            // 
            var directive = {
                //link: link,
                restrict: 'EA', //This means that it will be used as an attribute and NOT as an element. I don't like creating custom HTML elements
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: "header.html"
                //require: '^MainController'
                //scope: { user: '=' }
                ,controller: 'MainController'
                ,controllerAs: 'main'
            };
            return directive;

            //function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            //}
        }
    })();
```

Footer Directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('menuApp')
        .directive('footerDirective', footerDirective);

    footerDirective.$inject = ['$window'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function footerDirective($window) {
        // Usage:
        // 
        // Creates:
        // 
        var directive = {
            //link: link,
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'footer.html',
            require: "^headerDirective"
            //scope: {'main.user': '='}, // This is one of the cool things :). Will be explained in post.
            //,controller: 'MainController'
            //,controllerAs: 'main'
        };
        return directive;

        //function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        //}
    }
})();
```

Header template:

```
<div>

    <p>Scope user: {{ user }} </p>

    <p>Main user: {{ main.user }}</p>
    <hr/>

    <p>
        This part of the header is always here
    </p>

    <p ng-if="user">
        User is logged in :D
    </p>

    <p ng-if="!user">
        Hey buddy, log in! Be cool
    </p>
    <hr/>

    <p>Scope user: <input ng-model="user"> {{ user }}</p>

    <p>Main user: <input ng-model="main.user"> {{ main.user }}</p>

</div>
```

Footer template:

```
<md-toolbar class="md-medium-tall">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex>
        <span>FOOTER</span>
    </div>
    $SCOPE USER: {{ user }}
    <hr/>
    MAIN USER: {{ main.user }}
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Could you provide a plunker with your actual app ? Anyway i feel like what you want to do is to configure the Isolated Scope of your directive. Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive on the Isolated Scope part.

Answer (score 0):

If your directives sitting outside of the controller div, you will not be able to access the scope of your controller no matter how you will configure the directives scope.

You can use a service and inject the service to the the MainCtrl and to the directives or a good practices for your use case is to put a Parent controller that will be the global scope of your app. Then you configure your directives scope to inherit from the Parent controller

for example

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <div header-directive></div>
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
  </div>
  <div footer-directive></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I have in mind is a big app. It could have 5-6 tabs and a main content area that changes according to the selected tab. Some or all of them might want to have access to the same data in order to read or alter it. I am generally trying to work without $scope variables. Is it possible or recommended that I have many directives, each with its own template but the same controller bind to them? So that they can access and change values related to that controller? (I know that it is not the controller's job to keep vars etc. but I am trying to get the big picture)

Comment: I don't like the idea of attaching the same controller to multiple directives. Directive should be independent components. So i will put all of the global data inside Parent controller like in my example